# i want to convert the object type into j-son to post the data in the rest api when user clicks the submit button

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
   <form >

     <label for="ProductID">ProductID</label>
     <input type="text" id="id" name="firstname" placeholder="ProductID">

     <label for="productTitle">Product title</label>
     <input type="text" id="title" name="lastname" placeholder="productTitle">


     <br><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn">
   </form>
 <script>
var md = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
var data  = JSON.stringify(md) // it  convert into string
var myArr = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(typeof myArr);// it is returning object
</script>
 </div>
</body>
```

i want to to convert the data into j-son format when user click the submit-button  so that i can post the data  to the rest api  I used
 JSON.parse to convert into json  but it is not working

Comment: You can't serialize HTML elements with JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to serialize the form by clicking the submit button.

Form to Json: Loop all input elements and change to json.

Json to Form: Loop the json object and set input's value.

```js
function toJSONString( form ) {
    var obj = {};
    var elements = form.querySelectorAll( "input, select, textarea" );
    for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var name = element.name;
        var value = element.value;

    if( name ) {
            obj[ name ] = value;
        }
    }

    return JSON.stringify( obj );
}

function toFormValue( string ) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(string);
    
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var content = obj[key];
            var input = document.getElementsByName(key)[0];
            input.value = content;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
     <form id="form">

       <label for="ProductID">ProductID</label>
       <input type="text" id="id" name="firstname" placeholder="ProductID">

       <label for="productTitle">Product title</label>
       <input type="text" id="title" name="lastname" placeholder="productTitle">


       <br><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn">
     </form>
     <button onclick="toFormValue(json)">Set</button>
   <script>
    var json = {};
    var form = document.getElementById( "form" );
    form.addEventListener( "submit", function( e ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var r = toJSONString( this );
      json = r;
      console.log(json);

    }, false);
  </script>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```